# How can I read a csv file using panda dataframe from GPU?

Tags: python-3.x, gpu, h2o, h2o4gpu

I am reading a file using
 `file=pd.read_csv('file_1.csv'`)

which is taking a long time on **CPU**.

Is there any method to read this using **GPU**.

Comment: https://blog.dask.org/2019/01/13/dask-cudf-first-steps 
This might be helpful

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. The biggest bottleneck is IO and that’s handled by the CPU.

Comment: What is the maximum data size that a panda dataframe can read ?

Comment: @AnshulGupta That should be a new question, but don't do that, as it  is easy to google for. (The answer appears to be: as much as you have RAM for, assuming it is 64-bit python.)